# Maven surefire plugin hangs forever

Tags: java, maven-2

My project install was perfectly fine until yesterday but today my install gets stuck at the following,

Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 20:16:01+0100)

Java version: 1.6.0_20

`[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Perforce\project-name\target\surefire-reports`

Basically after this line the install does not proceed at all. Any thoughts?

1. I have tried mvn -X and I get the same thing.
2. I have even upgraded to version 2.6 the latest and still get the same issue
3. I have ensured that there are no debug options i.e, the JVM is not waiting for any debugger to attach(-Xdebug options)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I passed the forkMode=never and now I noticed that one of the tests was not starting up at all. The reason was that it was using a ehcache and stored entries in the "java.io.tmpdir" directory which was my user's temporary directory.

The system also started being slow from today. Then I noticed that my C:/users/../AppData/Local/Temp folder had about 2 million files most of them either p4ticket234234.txt or Visual studio log files.

Once I cleared these log files, my build went successful. A jconsole or some thread dump would have more indicated the same I think.

Comment: Btw; I fixed this problem for surefire 2.7

Answer (score 2):

Make a thread dump of the correct process using jstack and submit an issue

Comment: yeah... if I could do that against github actions... we are facing the same issue that OP is, 13 years ago, in version `3.1.2`. Our builds are public, and you can see [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/actions/runs/6328829205/job/17188039904) that it simply hangs until the stage is killed.

Answer (score 1):

Surefire waits for all non-daemon threads in your application to finish. It's easy to miss one or another. For example make sure to call the [shutdown](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown%28%29) method on your `Executors` if you use any. If you do thread handling on your own you basically have to either make them [daemon](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon%28boolean%29) threads or make sure they terminate. A thread dump might help to spot the lingering threads.

Answer (score 0):

Use jps, jstack or jvisualvm tools from JDK to get list of processes and their thread dumps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. All of a sudden my "mvn test" was hanging seemingly forever and the related org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter
 process was taking 1.7GB! After much investigation it turns out that the problem was that I had deleted a class that was being instantiated by spring-core as a spring bean within the spring XML configuration. Once I removed the  element corresponding to the deleted class from the spring XML configuration all was well. This seems like a bug in spring and surefire usage where no reasonable warning or error is produced.